# What else does Magical Maintenance do?

Tags: harry-potter

Magical Maintenance is a branch of the ministry containing a bunch of people wearing blue robes who work at the ministry.  One thing they do is control the weather:

> "Mr. Weasley," said Harry, as they passed a window through which sunlight was streaming, "aren't we underground?"
>
> "Yes, we are," said Mr. Weasley, "those are enchanted windows; Magical Maintenance decide what weather we're getting every day.  We had two months of hurricanes last time they were angling for a pay raise..."

So Magical Maintenance controls the weather.  And I assume they are there for maintaining the Ministry.  But are there any specific instances in books or movies of jobs done by Magical Maintenance?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ministry_of_Magic_lift_attendant

Comment: Reg Cattermole was at Magical Maintenance, and was expected to sort out a problem with **rain in an office**. Would you count this under what you've already mentioned (controlling the weather), or would it be worth an answer?

Comment: It's just one thing, and it (I hope) doesn't happen very often.  More would be nice, but if nothing else can be found in canon, it would do.

Comment: Could say its like a regular office maintenance worker but magical, making sure the lifts work, making sure the loos that flush people into the ministry work, first line support for floo powder chimneys being faulty, temperature maintenance, and in general just no magical or physical disturbance around the building that could interrupt normal working pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not precisely... the enchanted windows SHOW weather outside, but in reality, the Ministry of Magic is underground. In the quote you provided, they acknowledged that, and showed exactly what MM does - they provide the maintenance for the (highly magical) Ministry of Magic building, including things like ambiance. They're the janitors, those that make sure the lifts work, make sure everything is the right temperature, that the trash is disposed of properly, cleaning up after owls, cleaning and stocking magical materials. We don't run into many, but here are the three that we know about:

1. The person Ron was impersonating, Reg Cattermole, worked in MM, and
   had to fix the weather in someone's office... that's not "control of
   weather" but rather control of the magics in the office.
2. Via Pottermore, we know that [Dolores Umbridge's father, Orford, was in the MM dept. He is only mentioned to have swept and mopped the floors](http://www.pottermore.com/en/book5/chapter13/moment1/dolores-umbridge).
3. The unnamed lift attendant - while this doesn't show something
   specific about the role, you can deduce by his presence that wizards
   and witches have a standoffish approach to technology, similar to
   the average Muggle prior to the 1960s.

Comment: Didn't exactly get my question--I was asking for specific examples in canon of jobs they do (and I understand that the MoM is  underground) but you did give me what I was asking for.